# Is there an easy way to import data into SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

At the moment I am having to write out each query to insert data into the database separately.

Is there a way I can import a spreadsheet or anything else and end up with this form.?

Is there an auto-increment feature like in normal MySQL?

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " Values ('3','" +
            "Question'," +
            "'Answer1'," +
            "'Answer2'," +
            "'Answer3'," +
            "'Answer4'," +
            "'Correctanswer'," +
            "'Reason');");
```

Comment: If you mean that you need to do bulk loads into the database, and you'd like to optimize the load time, then let me refer you to a blog post that I wrote: http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Also is there an autoincrement feature like in normal Mysql?

Yes. Take a look at: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

With regards to your original question; for those cases I better create the database and the initial data in my computer using any of the Sqlite DB Managers out there. Then, I put the database inside the assets directory of the project and instead of creating the database *the normal way*, I copy the database from there to the handset. This like could be helpful in that case:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 1):

- If you can use the SQLite Command Line Shell to prepare your database, you can **.import** into a table from a file
- If your data is (contained in) a spreadsheet, consider using the spreadsheets scripting/macro language to **export** table(s) INTO a SQLite database
- For lots of tables preparing a master database and **attach**-ing to that from your app may be more efficient and could be done on the handset only
- wrt to autoincrement, look at [the autoincrement faq](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to initialize your database with some values, but you don't want to hardcode each query.

In this case you should use JSON to store your data in an external file (like a spreadsheet), then parse this file to get your data and use it to generate your SQL queries.

Here is [a tutorial](http://www.newtondev.com/2010/11/19/parsing-and-working-with-json-in-google-android/) on how to use JSON in android apps.